# Programmatically create HTML table from D3 nested JSON object

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, d3.js

I'm trying to make tables for a dashboard using React/D3. One of them is similar to this HTML hard-coded table which I'm trying to make:

```css
table, td{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <td>Location</td>
    <td>State</td>
    <td># Jobs</td>
  </thead>
  
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">Cell 1 spanning if we have multiple values for this key</td>
      <td>SUCCESSFUL</td>
      <td>75</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>      
      <td>FAILED</td>
      <td>22</td>
    </tr>
    
  </tbody>
</table>
<br />
```

**Data**

The data is retrieved from a SQL-Server database through node-mssql and express and then stored in react state, I pull 7 days worth of data and filter this down to 1 day per component in my react app as i need it.

It returns as normal and has NO nesting in it e.g.

```
{
  "location": "Ireland",
  "state": "Finished",
  "finish_time": "2018-10-18T12:00:00",
  "seconds_passed": 30
}
```

**D3**

With D3 I aggregated this data so that, it would be aggregated by location, then by state and then a count of the rows in that aggregation. I achieved this with nest and rollup:

```
dailyJobStatusCounts = () => {
return (
  nest()
  .key( row => row.location)
  .key( row => row.state)
  .rollup(function(values) { return values.length; })
  .entries(this._filterTwentyFourHours())
);
```

}

This returns an object that looks like this:

```
[{"key":"Ireland","values":[{"key":"SUCCEEDED","value":14},{"key":"FAILED","value":7}]}]
```

**Rendering to HTML in React**

My issue occurs around my lack of understanding of how to render this nested JSON object as a HTML table. When attempting to render, I have tried two variations:

***React***

```
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th>State</th>
        <th># Jobs</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {data.map(row => {
        return <tr>
          <td>{row.key}</td>

          { row.values.map( v => {
            return <React.Fragment>
            <td>{v.key}</td>
            <td>{v.value}</td>
            </React.Fragment>
          })}

        </tr>
      })}
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Which renders the table like this:

***HTML Output***

```css
table, td {
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Location</th>
      <th>State</th>
      <th>Jobs</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>ie11</td>
      <td>SUCCEEDED</td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>FAILED</td>
      <td>7</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Or the other variation:

***React***

```
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th>State</th>
        <th># Jobs</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {data.map(row => {
        return <tr>
          <td>{row.key}</td>

          { row.values.map( v => {
            return <tr>
            <td>{v.key}</td>
            <td>{v.value}</td>
            </tr>
          })}

        </tr>
      })}
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

***HTML Output***

```css
table, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Location</th>
      <th>State</th>
      <th># Jobs</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>ie11</td>
      <tr>
        <td>SUCCEEDED</td>
        <td>13</td>
      </tr>
      
      <tr>
        <td>FAILED</td>
        <td>7</td>
      </tr>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I see that some of the HTML being output for table is not valid as I have nested  values, however I am struggling to get my head around how I can map this JSON object to display the HTML table with the rowspan mentioned at the beginning of this question. Thanks in advance for any answers.

*Looked at a somewhat similar SO question which is close, but I'm not sure it answers my use-case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28495689/putting-data-into-a-table-using-d3-js-after-a-nest-call)*

Comment: you have to transform your data further so it matches the tr-td structure needed.